# fullcalendar V3 how to add JET Context Menu

Tags: javascript, html, jet, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to incorporate context menu from https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=menu&demo=contextMenu
using full calender io events and i am unable to understand how to plug in oj component under fullcalender io events.

I am aware that context menus can be accomplised using jquery ui context menu, but i want to know how to use jet code from fullcalendar io events.

Can you please let me know how i can plug in the jet context menu in the below code?

`JET`

```
require(['ojs/ojoffcanvas','knockout','ojs/ojbootstrap','ojs/ojarraydataprovider','jquery','ojs/ojknockout',
      'fullCalendar','moment','jqueryui','jquerycontextmenu',
      'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojdiagram','ojs/ojformlayout','ojs/ojbutton',
        'ojs/ojmenu', 'ojs/ojoption','ojs/ojinputtext','ojs/ojselectcombobox'],

        function (ko, Bootstrap,ArrayDataProvider,$) {    

    
      function ChartModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.addressBookData = ko.observableArray([]);  
        self.columns = ko.observableArray([
            { headerText : 'title', field : 'title'},
            { headerText : 'start', field : 'start'},
            { headerText : 'end', field : 'end'},
            { headerText : 'QuantityOrdered', field : 'QuantityOrdered'},
            { headerText : 'QuantityCompleted', field : 'QuantityCompleted'}
        ])
        
   this.dataprovider = new ArrayDataProvider(self.addressBookData, { keyAttributes: 'title'});   
    
    }
    
function getE1Data(self,callback) {
    var input = {
        aliasNaming: true,
        findOnEntry: "TRUE",
        maxPageSize: "100",
        targetName: "XXX",
        aliasNaming : true, 
        targetType: "view",
        dataServiceType: "BROWSE",
        returnControlIDs: "TABLEX.DOCO|TABLEX.DL01|TABLEX.LITM|TABLEX.STRT|TABLEX.DRQJ|TABLEX.UORG|TABLEX.SOQS|TABLEX.SOCN|TABLEX.SRST"
    };
    
    callAISService(input, DATA_SERVICE, function(response) {
        if (response.message) {
            callback("failed");
        } else {
            renderData($,self,response.fs_DATABROWSE_V4801C.data.gridData.rowset);
            callback("success");
        }
    });
}

       
function renderData($,self,data)  {

    self = this;
    this.events = [];
      data.forEach(element => {
    const obj ={};
    const extendedProps ={};
        var teststr1 = (element.TABLEX_LITM.value).concat(" - ",(element.TABLEX_DOCO.value));
        var teststr2 = (element.TABLEX_DL01.value).concat(" - ",teststr1);
        obj.title = teststr2,
        obj.start = new Date(element.TABLEX_DRQJ.value),
        obj.end= new Date(element.TABLEX_STRT.value),
        extendedProps.QuantityOrdered = element.TABLEX_UORG.value,
        extendedProps.QuantityCompleted = element.TABLEX_SOQS.value,
        extendedProps.QuantityScrapped = element.TABLEX_SOCN.value,
        extendedProps.WOStatus = element.TABLEX_SRST.value,
        obj.extendedProps = extendedProps,
        events.push(obj); 
});  
  
    this.calendar = $ ('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
    editable: true,
    weekends : true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper:true,
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    displayEventTime: false,
    header:{
        left : 'prev,next,today',
        center : 'title',
        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },  

    events: events,
    
     eventClick: function(self,events) {
      console.log(events.extendedProps.QuantityOrdered);
      console.log(events.extendedProps.QuantityCompleted);
    },
   
    eventRender: function (events, element) {
        element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        element.click(function() {
            $("#startTime").html(formatDate(events.start));
            $("#endTime").html(formatDate(events.end));
            $("#QuantityOrdered").html(events.extendedProps.QuantityOrdered);   
            $("#QuantityCompleted").html(events.extendedProps.QuantityCompleted); 
            $("#QuantityScrapped").html(events.extendedProps.QuantityScrapped);
            $("#WOStatus").html(events.extendedProps.WOStatus);
            $("#eventContent").dialog({ modal: true, resizable: true ,effect: "explode",title: events.title, width:350});           
        });       
     
    }
}); 

}
 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chartModel = new ChartModel();
        getE1Data(chartModel,(status)=>{
            ko.applyBindings(chartModel, document.getElementById('calendar'));             
        });
    }); 
 });
```

`JET`

`HTML`

```
        <body 
        <br />
        <div class = "container">
        <div id = "calendar"> </div>
        </div>  
        </body>
```

`HTML`

Please find the below sample HTML, which used JET libraries like oj-menu using which context menu is acheived:

```
    <body id="content">
            <oj-input-text id="filter" class="oj-form-control-max-width-md" label-hint="Filter" label-edge="inside"
                           placeholder="Type to filter" on-raw-value-changed="[[handleValueChanged]]" value="{{filter}}" clear-icon="always">
              </oj-input-text>
           <oj-input-text id="filter1" class="oj-form-control-max-width-md" label-hint="Filter1" label-edge="inside"
                           placeholder="Type to filter" on-raw-value-changed="[[handleValueChanged1]]" value="{{filter1}}" clear-icon="always">
              </oj-input-text>
               <oj-input-text id="filter2" class="oj-form-control-max-width-md" label-hint="Filter1" label-edge="inside"
                           placeholder="Type to filter" on-raw-value-changed="[[handleValueChanged2]]" value="{{filter2}}" clear-icon="always">
              </oj-input-text>
                 <oj-table id='table' aria-label='Departments Table'
                                 data='[[dataprovider]]' 
                                 scroll-policy='loadMoreOnScroll'
                                 columns-default.sortable='disabled' 
                                 columns='{{columns}}'
                                 style='width:100%; height: 1000px;'> 
                                 
                <oj-menu id="ctxMenu" slot="contextMenu" aria-label="Match Edit">
                <oj-option value="Action 1">Work Centre Details</oj-option>
                <oj-option value="Action 12">Resource Units</oj-option>
                <oj-option value="Action 13">Work Day Calendar</oj-option>
                </oj-menu>
                
    <div id="eventContent" title="Event Details">
    <div id="eventInfo"></div>
    </div>
            </oj-table>
            
    </body>
```

Comment: what exactly is your requirement? You want a context menu attached to each event, or something?

Comment: Yes, i want to attach a context menu(using JET) to each event

Comment: I expect you would do something in the eventRender callback. I'm not really familiar with these oracle jet components. Are you able to attach a context menu to a regular HTML? how would you do that? if you show an example of that, for comparison, it might be possible to help you.

Comment: I have added the HTML which uses JET where context menu is acheived, i want to do the same for each event of full calendar io

Comment: Does there not have to be any JavaScript with that? Anyway, this seems hugely over-complicated just for a context menu...I think you'd be better with the jQuery plugin you were asking about in your other question.

Comment: sure, thank you, i wanted to explore the options from JET as well. I tried with jquery context menu , it didnt work for ill place the code which i tired in my previous question.